# Why is SSO not working on cas version 6.X.X?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have three applications in spring boot and the authentication is done through cas server (azure tenant). If a user logs in any of the three applications and tries to access any of the other two, I want them not to have to log in again but instead they are redirected to login page. Them problem introduced when I upgraded cas from 5.3.16 to 6.2.8. This used to work on the older version.

The services are loaded to cas from the following json files:

egate-1001.json
not-1003.json
sanction-1004.json

I'll post only one of them since they have the same structure.

not-1003.json:

```
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId": "https://${ENV_EGATE_HOST}/not/.*",
  "name": "Notifications",
  "description": "eGate Notifications application",
  "id": 1003,
  "matchingStrategy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.FullRegexRegisteredServiceMatchingStrategy"
  },
  "logoutType": "FRONT_CHANNEL",
  "logoutUrl": "https://${ENV_EGATE_HOST}/not/j_spring_cas_security_logout",
  "evaluationOrder": 10000003,
  "attributeReleasePolicy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllAttributeReleasePolicy"
  }
}
```

Here is the cas.properties file.

```
cas.server.name=https://${ENV_EGATE_HOST}
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}/cas
server.port=8443

cas.service-registry.init-from-json=false
cas.service-registry.json.location=file:${ENV_CAS_CONFIGPATH}/services

cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.type=AZURE
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.discoveryUri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/${ENV_AZURE_TENANTID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.logoutUrl=https://login.microsoftonline.com/${ENV_AZURE_TENANTID}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://${ENV_EGATE_HOST}/cas/
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.id=${ENV_AZURE_APPID}

cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.secret=${ENV_AZURE_SECRET}

cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.auto-redirect=false
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.clientName=${ENV_AZURE_APPNAME}
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.azureTenantId=${ENV_AZURE_TENANTID}

cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.responseType=code
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.useNonce=true
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].generic.scope=openid profile
cas.authn.pac4j.typedIdUsed=false
cas.view.cas2.v3ForwardCompatible=true

management.endpoints.enabled-by-default = true
management.endpoints.actuatorEndpointsEnabled = true
cas.monitor.endpoints.enabled = true
cas.monitor.endpoints.sensitive = false

cas.authn.pac4j.cookie.crypto.encryption.key=${ENV_CAS_COOKIE_ENCRYPRION_KEY}
cas.authn.pac4j.cookie.crypto.signing.key=${ENV_CAS_COOKIE_SIGNING_KEY}
cas.tgc.crypto.encryption.key=${ENV_CAS_TGC_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
cas.tgc.crypto.signing.key=${ENV_CAS_TGC_SIGNING_KEY}
cas.webflow.crypto.signing.key=${ENV_CAS_WEBFLOW_SIGNING_KEY}
cas.webflow.crypto.encryption.key=${ENV_CAS_WEBFLOW_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
```

For each application there is a spring-security.xml file. They are written according to this documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/cas.html

I tried different versions of cas from version 6 and above but it didn't work.

Any ideas of what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check that the CAS SSO cookie called "TGC" is accepted by your browser after a successful login and sent back to CAS? You can check available "cas.tgc.*" configuration properties here: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.6.x/authentication/Configuring-SSO.html#configuration.

Comment: @PetrBodnár The /cas/login returns the TGC cookie but its max age is set to 0, so it's never stored on the browser. I tried to change its max age (cas.tgc.max-age), although its default value is until browser shutdown, but it is still set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of CAS not remembering your SSO session seems to be caused by CAS not correctly returning the `Set-Cookie` header(s) with the CAS SSO cookie *when a delegated authentication, like Azure in this case, is used*, under some circumstances.

This problem, probably a bug, is more thoroughly discussed at [CAS 6.2.X: TGC Cookie set twice](https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/g/cas-user/c/xsc-_CTMjvA/) and more freshly also at [Still struggling with Azure AD delegated login](https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/g/cas-user/c/QWRAFfqFwqY/).

According to the linked forum pages, the only working workaround/solution so far is to comment out the line `ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator.removeCookie(response);` in the Java class [InitialFlowSetupAction](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/6.2.x/support/cas-server-support-actions/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/web/flow/login/InitialFlowSetupAction.java) (i.e. to override this class within your CAS overlay project).